# quoted_identifier on?

Tags: sql-server, quoted-identifier

One of our programs is erroring out because a stored procedure was "created with QUOTED_IDENTIFIER option ON". This is a Microsoft SQL Server (8).

All that happened to it yesterday was:
Stored procedures were editted.
A table was created.

I have removed the edits. I have deleted the table. The error is still coming up.

Is there a query (or something), so I can figure out which stored procedure is causing the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run the profiler and capture error events and SP:Starting and SP:Completed events